# How to skip test task when running sonarqube task?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

When I execute sonarqube task, by default test task runs. How can I configure Gradle to not run tests when I specifically run sonarqube.

I want to configure this `build.gradle.kts`.

When I run

```
./gradlew sonarqube -x test
```

then tests are not executed.

I want to achieve the same by configuring in the `build.gradle.kts` file.

Comment: did you try https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/#header-8

Comment: Yes, I followed the link for setting up sonarqube task. However, I could not find a reference to skip a particular gradle task.